# JavaScript regular expression failing mysteriously on the word "tennis"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

We wrote a small script in JavaScript to find duplicates or potential duplicates. The script works sometimes, but it fails mysteriously on some words like "tennis." We're using jQuery.

Steps:

1) Click on the JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Hgex/.

2) Click **Check Dupes**.

3) Under the section **Repeat Words**, the word **tennis** should list two entries, one for **watching tennis match** and one for **serving tennis ball**. However, for some reason the regular expression fails when checking the **serving tennis ball** phrase -- unless we replace the variables and hard code values using Chrome Developer Tools. All the values look right when we use breakpoints yet the RegEx fails for this phrase.

Any clue what we're doing wrong?

Thanks!

**JavaScript:**

```
    // Init page
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        init();
    });


    function init() {
        $( '#box .button.dupe_clues' ).on( 'mousedown', function() {
            var dupe_words_list = $( '.list.dupe_words' );
            dupe_words_list.empty();
            var dupe_words = ['tennis'];
            var unique_clues = ['watching tennis match', 'serving tennis ball'];
            $( dupe_words ).each( function() {
                var highlighted_clues = highlight_dupe_word( unique_clues, this );
                dupe_words_list.append( '<div>' + this + ': ' + highlighted_clues + '</div>' );
            });
        });
    }


function highlight_dupe_word( clues, word ) {
    var list = '';

    // Find all clues containing this word
    var escaped_word = word.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    var re = new RegExp( '\\b' + escaped_word + '\\b', 'gi' );
    $( clues ).each( function(i, text) {
        if ( re.test( text ) ) {
            list = list + ', ' + text;
        }
    });

    // Trim leading comma
    if ( list.length > 0 ) {
        list = list.substring( 2, list.length + 1 );
    }

    // Return list
    return ( list );
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id='box'>
    <textarea id='clues'>
                 watching tennis match
                 serving tennis ball       
    </textarea>

    <div class='button_box'>
        <div class='button dupe_clues'>Check Dupes</div>
    </div>


    <div class='results'>
        <div class='title'>Safe Clues</div>
        <div class='unique_clues list'></div>
        <div class='title'>Repeat Words</div>
        <div class='dupe_words list'></div>
        <div class='title'>Dupe Clues</div>
        <div class='dupe_clues list'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a lot of code to try debugging, but your problem is not with the regular expression; change your clues list to show only `watching hockey match`, `playing hockey game`, and `holding hockey stick`. You'll get the correct repeat word, but again only two of the three show up. It's somewhere in your `.each` iterations or `if/else` statements.

Comment: please simplify demo and code displayed down to bare minimum to replicate issue. There is no need to put more than just a few words in, nor to display methods that are working

Comment: ok updated and streamlined code to replicate issue.

Comment: demo still full of irrelevant garbage

Comment: To clarify, a demo doesn't need to be a stripped down working demo of the whole project; just a working replication of the problem in and of itself.

Comment: ok, we'll try stripping more.

Comment: ok, JS stripped to the bone! thanks for your patience.

Comment: Big clue -- it only fails when the phrase (like the 2 tennis phrases) are adjacent in your list!  Separate the two tennis phrases, and they correctly list in your dupes.

Comment: An even more 'stripped to the bone' example: `var re = new RegExp('\\btennis\\b', 'gi'); console.log(re.test('watching tennis match')); console.log(re.test('serving tennis ball'));`

Comment: @Crashalot  you can strip the a lot more, as tom said, remove CSS, put just the lines where the problem is.. the line with RegExp()..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `g` flag.

```
var re = new RegExp( '\\b' + escaped_word + '\\b', 'i' );
```

The `g` flag causes the `RegExp` object to remember its position and resume the search from there when `test()` is called again. In your case, each call should start at the beginning of the string.

Comment: ahhh, interesting. so even though the string changes, the regex remembers its position?

Comment: @Crashalot, yes. See ECMA sections [15.10.6.3 RegExp.prototype.test(string)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3) and [15.10.6.2 RegExp.prototype.exec(string)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2) for the details.